# Trying to disable xp_Cmdshell and rpc_out and and receiving mixed results

Tags: sql-server, vulnerability-assessment

I'm trying to disable `xp_Cmdshell` and `rpc_out` and when I run the commands on query analyzer it shows it's disabled.

But after this I need to run a security scan report which provides me the following report that it's has not been disabled. Can anyone help me?

> 5 Microsoft SQL Server Database Link Crawling Command Execution
>
> QID:
>   19824
>
> Category:
>   Database
>
> CVE ID:
>   `-`
>
> Vendor Reference
>   `-`
>
> Bugtraq ID:
>   `-`
>
> Service Modified:
>   02/20/2013
>
> User Modified:
>   `-`
>
> Edited:
>   No
>
> PCI Vuln:
>   Yes
>
> THREAT:
>   Microsoft SQL Server is exposed to a remote command execution vulnerability.
>
> Affected Versions:
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 are affected.
>
> IMPACT:
>   Successful exploitation could allow attackers to obtain sensitive information and execute arbitrary code.
>
> SOLUTION:
>   There are no solutions available at this time.
>   Workaround:
>   Disable RPC_Out and xp_cmdshell for this issue.
>
> COMPLIANCE:
>   Not Applicable
>
> EXPLOITABILITY:
>   There is no exploitability information for this vulnerability.
>
> ASSOCIATED MALWARE:
>   There is no malware information for this vulnerability.
>
> RESULTS:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe Version is 2009.100.4000.0

Comment: You have to run RECONFIGURE when you disable those configuration options.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the actual value with the following tiny script:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.configurations
where name='xp_cmdshell'
```

You can also do it this way to see all advanced options:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your security scanning software is likely identifying your system running sql server and highlighting this as a risk.  There is no actual validation of a risk through code, just flagging it as a possibility due to the presence of the SQL Server executables.

I have this same 'vulnerability' on my system while having xp_cmdshell disabled and no linked servers presents.  Linked servers would have the option of 'RPC_OUT'.  You can review your settings and then mark the issue as resolved/closed in your tracking system as there is nothing to do.